# autowiring 2 instances of the same class but with different properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

i want to check my constructor in a particular class that counts on properties from .properties file.
if some property is missing than assign some default value.
i'm using `@Value` in order to catch the properties in the constructor.

my problem is that when i want to check both behaviors in the same test class i dont know how delete the wanted property from the context **just for 1 instance**.
the instantioation occurs with `@Autowired`

i tired to clear this property by key but it happens after the autowiring and both get the property.

Comment: Consider refactoring to have two separate tests.  If they have similar setup, make a shared setup method they can both call, but then change the aspects that make them different.

Comment: this is not the behavior that i want to check.... of course i can change the property manually after creation. i want to check the instantiation without interrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classToInstatiate, "your.prop", "someValue");
```

to test the default behaviour

Comment: this is exactly what i dont want to do.